# How to create a dyanmic virtual host in wamp stack

Tags: php, wamp, virtualhost

Iam finding a way to dynamicaly create vhosts I tried this one but it's not working

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/WAMP/apache2/htdocs/projects/%0/current"
    VirtualScriptAlias "D:/WAMP/apache2/htdocs/projects/%0/current"
    LogLevel debug
    <Directory "D:/WAMP/apache2/htdocs/projects/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I set the hosts file too but when I load my vhost name it would load the localhost index file instead of my project. I just want to do this to make less hassle setting up new projects :) thanks. I'm using windows 8.1.

Comment: _I didnt make a symlink yet i just created a folder to a test project named current is that the cause?:_ Why didn't you try to create that symlink before asking your question?

Comment: @honk I tried it but still not yet working. better edit my note there